# In Java, send http get/post request for the specified ipaddress

Tags: java, http

In my java application, i want to send http request for the specific user(Ip address). ie, the request "http://search.barnesandnoble.com/booksearch/first%20book.pdf" should be send from specified user(xxx.xx.xx.x(IP address)) in my code. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Short answer: you cannot. The external IP address is automatically added as the TCP/IP packet is routed to the destination. Manually crafting packets is outside the scope of a standard network stack - and Java - even if such would correctly reach their intended destination. (Even if the outbound IP *was* forged the TCP handshake, and thus the HTTP GET/POST, would fail because the server could not respond.)

Comment: I've linked this to a generic question on spoofing your IP address.  But the practical answer is: 1) it is technically difficult, 2) it is a really, really bad idea if you are doing it for an ostensibly good reason, and 3) if you are doing it for nefarious reasons ... GO AWAY!

Comment: Thanks for your reply on time. Is there any way to send http request to the specific user(Ip address). for example, need to send http://xxx.xx.x.xxx:port//*****.do?